# Ошибка при работе с фильтрацией в EasyAdminBundle

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

Есть Entity User с полем **isEnabled(bool)**, так же есть **EasyAdminBundle** в системе, в конфигурации для него где страница со списком всех сущностей **List** добавляю фильтр с полем isEnabled как сказано в [документации](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/list-search-show-configuration.html#filtering-results)

```
easy_admin:
    entities:
        Users:
            class: App\Entity\User
            list:
                filters: ['isEnabled']
```

Фильтра на странице появляется, но при нажатии на чекбокс 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получаю в консоле ошибку **js app.js:77 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value** и фильтр не работает.

Может у кого-то уже было такое, подскажите, пожалуйста, как решит или хоть в какую сторону искать?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня "easycorp/easyadmin-bundle": "^2.3". Попробовал добавить у себя фильтры `filters: ['id', 'question']` - ошибок никаких в консоли нет.